# Two Sums in C: segmentation fault when testing

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I completed and passed the leetcode Two Sums question, but somehow when I tried to write tests on my own, I kept bumping into segmentation fault. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


int *twoSum(int *nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){
    *returnSize = 2;
    int *returnValues = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < numsSize; j++) {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                returnValues[0] = i;
                returnValues[1] = j;
                return returnValues;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return returnValues;
}

int main(){
    int nums[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
    int size = 6;
    int* resultSize;
    printf("First index:%d  \n", (twoSum(nums, size, 9, resultSize))[0]);
    printf("Second index:%d  \n", (twoSum(nums, size, 9, resultSize))[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

I tried to remove the variable *returnSize in the twoSum function and solved the issue. But since the original question requires this *returnSize variable, I don't know how to pull out the items in twoSum return array without encountering segmentation fault while still using *returnSize.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The variable `resultSize` is a pointer, but *where does it point?* Define it as a non-pointer variable, and use the pointer-to operator `&` to pass a pointer to it. Or is it even needed, since the returned size will *always* be equal to `2`?

Comment: On another note, you have memory leaks in your program.

Comment: Resultsize is a pointer but you have no allocated memory for using it. Just like you did with returnvalues. But  I don't understand why are you using a pointer there.

Answer (score 0):

`*returnSize = 2;` tries to write the value 2 to a pointer (i.e. memory address) that is not initialized (i.e. it contains an indeterminate value), which causes the segfault. Instead, declare `resultSize` as a regular `int` (which reserves memory for it) and then pass a *pointer* to that `int` to the function:

```
int resultSize;
printf("First index:%d  \n", (twoSum(nums, size, 9, &resultSize))[0]);
printf("Second index:%d  \n", (twoSum(nums, size, 9, &resultSize))[1]);
```

You may also want to store the pointer returned by `twoSum` in the `main` function, so that you can free it after printing the results.

Side note: The math header is unused.